# How to install enable different version of Java concurrently on Linux Mint?

Tags: java, ubuntu, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint.

My web project is using Java 6. I run it in terminal with Gradle.

I want to use FindBugs, which requires Java 7.

My question is, how to run Java 7 in desktop environment, and run Java 6 in terminal at the same time?

Comment: You can install multiple java versions and most of the web servers have the option to specify JAVA_HOME location. When you run standalone application, use absolute java path, e.g. /usr/java/jre1.6/bin/java -jar MyApp.jar

Comment: check this link: http://lj4newbies.blogspot.in/2007/04/2-jvm-on-one-linux-box.html